# nodejs graphql - localhost:3001 doesn't load

Tags: node.js, apollo-server

Loading localhost:3001 which worked for me before, stopped working for me all of a sudden. I am not seeing anything wrong on the code and I am getting server started message as well when run the server. But localhost:3001 doesn't seem to be loading.

here is the code -

```
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');
const cors = require('cors');//to have this api accessed by multiple domains
const dotEnv = require('dotenv');

dotEnv.config();

const app = express();

//middleware
app.use(cors);
app.use(express.json());

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Query {
        greetings: String
    }
`;

const resolvers = {};

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
});

apolloServer.applyMiddleware({app, path: '/graphql'});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use('/', (req,res, next) => {
    res.send({message: 'Hello Sumesh'});
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on PORT: ${PORT}`);
    console.log(`GraphQL Endpoint: ${apolloServer.graphqlPath}`);
});
```

Here is the terminal output when the server running -
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesnt load"? Did you specify the `PORT` variable? Your app seems to operate on port `3000` by default.

Comment: The PORT is set on .env file, the output says it is running on 3001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with your cors middleware statement. It should be:

```
app.use(cors());
```

instead of

```
app.use(cors);
```